# Trouble geting BCP to work on local server

Tags: sql-server, bcp

This is driving me mad...

SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition installed.

Attempting to BCP to a file from the command line.

```
bcp MyDb..MyTable out MyTable.dat -T
```

Get the error:

> CTLIB Message:  - XX/XX/XX/XX/X/X:
>   ct_connect(): directory service layer: internal directory control
>   layer error: Requested server name not found.
>   Establishing connection failed.

Comment: Hmm..... can't reproduce - works just fine here. Are you sure your SQL Server is up and running?

Comment: Yep, SQL Server is fine for everything else. I've used BCP before in this manner, but not in this company.

Comment: Does this SQL Server maybe not support Trusted connections? Have you tried with `-U (userid) -P (pwd)` ? Also: have you tried explicitly specifying the server with `-S (local)` - any luck?

Comment: The local sql server does support trusted connections, however, all the varying combinations of -S -U and -P still give the same error.

When using -T the command line prompts for a password before giving the error(?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out Sybase is installed on these corporate desktops and gets path priority over SQL. When I ran BCP from the command line it was running Sybase BCP!

The answer to is specify the BCP path for SQL.  Now it works fine.